# Close last opened tab

Tags: python, browser

Can I close last opened tab (without closing the browser) from *Python* that was opened with the following code?

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get("firefox").open_new_tab(url)
```

You can use whatever for this tasks. I know that *webbrowser* module is not able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can send the hotkey combination to close the tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>) using the `pykeyboard` library from here, https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput.

Comment: The PyUserInput package is deprecated, it's replacement is [pynput](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't close browser programmatically(without hacking or create plug-in).

the [browser controller](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#browser-controller-objects) only provide methods to open browser but not to close.

this implicitly call new Process then parse command-line arguments such as

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("firefox -new-tab %s" % url, shell=True)
```

equal to open shell cmd:

> C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox -new-tab
>   http://docs.python.org

also most standard browser include Firefox provided its [command line args](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) to open new windows/tab but nothing to close opened tab.

Comment: I don't want to close browser. I only want to close active tab.