# Python Selenium How To Close All Other Tabs Except First Tab

Tags: python, selenium, tabs

I want to close all other tabs except the first opened tab in Selenium. How can I do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and Selenium - Close all tabs without closing the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141407/python-and-selenium-close-all-tabs-without-closing-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to any open tab with code like

```py
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Where `1`, `2` etc will be the tab indices.
The first tab will have index `0`.
So, after switching to any tab you can close that tab with

```py
driver.close()
```

And then switch back to the first tab with

```py
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

You can do that in a loop / repeat this action until all unnecessary tabs are closed / only 1 tab is existing.